# Problem with Texpad - Forest package Tree results in error: TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [parameter stack size=120]"

Tags: forest, trees, texpad

I recently got back reviews for a paper I submitted eight months ago. Upon opening my file, I discovered it wouldn't compile properly anymore. After some troubleshooting, I narrowed it down to the linguistic tree I drew using the Forest package. I tried compiling the tree in a dummy document. Then I tried a dummy tree in a dummy document. But as soon as I put in `\begin{forest}\end{forest}`, the same error pops up

(`TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [parameter stack size=120]`).

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}    

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
[CP[C][IP[I][VP[V][NP]]]]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

As I said, I haven't worked on the document in quite a while, but it used to compile with no issues. If I paste my MWE in a web-based Latex editor (overleaf), it compiles without issue. Perhaps this is an issue with Texpad? Has there been an update causing this incompatibility?

I have searched for similar issues, but as yet to no avail.

Comment: This is probably unrelated to your editor. I would rather suspect different version of packages. Compare the .log file from your computer to the one from overleaf and see if any of the packages have a different version.

Comment: btw: your MWE compiles fine for me with up-to-date pdflatex from texlive2018.

Comment: @samcarter check the last line of the log:-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the TexPad editor, make sure to use the external typesetter, not TexPad's internal one. That will not typeset for me, but the external one will.

Answer (score 3):

If I run the example with texlive it completes without error but the end of the log says

```
 133i,9n,160p,1577b,1258s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
```

so it used 160 slots in the parameter stack. You show you are using a tex with a stack of size 120 which is too small. (as shown above current texlive defaults to 10000)

Comment: Switching from the internal typesetter to the external one in Texpad did the trick!